# How to configure line spacing of a word-wrap label?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set size of line spacing between a word-wrap label ? Because if it's a different label, i can use 
 or margin but how to do it with only a label?

```
.blue-div {

min-height: 70px;

left: 0;
right: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
top:-12%;
/* /transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
position: absolute;
background-color: #003777;
z-index: 130;
border-radius: 10px;

text-align:center;
display:flex;
```

}

```
 <div class="blue-div">
          <label class="labelBluediv">Voucher Voucher Voucher Voucher Voucher Voucher Voucher Voucher</label>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Try using line-height property

Comment: thanks @Ramya, i forgot about line-height lol